# Poisson Summation Formula for Square-Integrable Functions on Locally Compact Abelian Groups

Tags: harmonic-analysis

The Poisson Summation Formula (PSF) is most often stated with the requirement that the functions in question be in $L^{1}$. However, after doing some searching, I found that there is a paper by R.P. Boas, Jr., [Poisson's summation formula in $L^2$](https://academic.oup.com/jlms/article-abstract/s1-21/2/102/2194180) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=19760)), which extends the PSF to square-integrable functions in the case of $L^{2}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$. As such, I was wondering where I might be able to find a generalization of this result to functions defined on $L^{2}\left(G\right)$, where $G$ is an arbitrary locally compact abelian group.

If it helps, I'm only *really* interested in the case where $G$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$—or, equivalently, their duals, $\mathbb{A}/\mathbb{Q}$ (the $\mathbb{Q}$-adeles mod $\mathbb{Q}$) and $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$  (the profinite integers).

Comment: The Pontryagin dual of $Q$ is a connected compact group, which is not $A$.

Comment: Indeed, as @YCor notes, the dual of a discrete abelian group (such as $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$) is compact, and vice-versa.

Comment: I've been following these articles: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/characterQ.pdf ;;;

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bffd/643d972eab01c0b063c34ad1560791899d3a.pdf ;;;


https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.01964.pdf

Comment: Fixed it; the dual was the $\mathbb{Q}$-adeles *mod* $\mathbb{Q}$.